# How to practice solfege?

Tags: practice, solfege

I have a solfege test coming up and I want to practice some more.
What is a good website to practice solfege on? (Preferably free)
And what are some general tips to get better at it?

Comment: Learn Doe, a Deer from the Sound of Music.

Answer (score 1):

In music theory  from Ricci Adams you have online exercise [note exercise](http://www.musictheory.net/exercises/note) on top the is a toggle switch which you could change from letters  to solfege. I hope I was a help.